# Not primary error writing data frame to MongoDB

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I cannot write any data to my MongoDB using R mongolite. I consistently get: `Error: not primary` error.

```
collection <- mongolite::mongo(url=my_url, db=my_db, collection=my_collection)
collection$insert(iris)

Error: not primary
```

This `Error: not primary` message occurs whatever I try to insert.

The database works fine, as I can write to it using Python without any problems.

I would appreciate any help!

- Tried other data frames, JSON objects, lists, ...
- Tried inserting a hand-written JSON string, like this: `collection$insert('{"a": 3}')`
- Tried if I could `find` in the same database using mongolite (yes)
- Tried if I could write using Python (yes)
- Checked Mongolite documentation and github

Comment: What URL are you using?

Comment: The URL is similar to this: `mongodb://username:password@host`, where the host is on the company intranet

Comment: If the driver does not support unified topology, you will need to add the `replicaSet=name` connection string option

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it's still not working.